# Unable to draw tabular view for images in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering

I am trying to draw a table of images using images from my asset folder. However I always get a blank black screen.If I replace the images with textbuttons, then I am able to draw the buttons in tabular form.

Now, my confusion is that "Image" class and "Textbutton", both extend actor class and therefore can be added to the stage object. Then why am I unable to draw the tabular form for images but can draw for textbuttons ? What information am I missing here ?

Following is the code snippet :

```
package com.mygdx.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class MyClass extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Image img;
TextButton btn;

private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
private Table table;
private Array<Image> tableImages;
private Array<TextButton> tableButtons;

@Override
public void create () {
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    table = new Table();
    table.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
    table.align(Align.center|Align.top);
    table.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    tableImages = new Array<Image>();
    tableButtons = new Array<TextButton>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        String filename = "circles/c" + (i + 1) + ".png";
        System.out.println(filename + " added ");
        img = new Image(new Texture(filename));
        tableImages.add(img); //this does NOT WORK !
        //tableButtons.add(new TextButton("click me", skin));  //this works
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            table.add(tableImages.get(3*i + j));
            //table.add(tableButtons.get(3*i + j));
        }
        table.row();
    }
    stage.addActor(table);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

}

It seems that we need to explicitly mention the size of the image during image creation and also the size of the cell when the image is added to the table cell. I am yet to confirm the mandatory fields froom java docs but till then, the working solution is posted below.

```
package com.mygdx.hyperscan;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class HyperScan extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Image img;
TextButton btn;

private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
private Table table;
private Array<Image> tableImages;
private Array<TextButton> tableButtons;

@Override
public void create () {
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    table = new Table();
    table.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
    table.align(Align.center|Align.top);
    table.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    tableImages = new Array<Image>();
    tableButtons = new Array<TextButton>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        String filename = "circles/c" + (i + 1) + ".png";
        //System.out.println(filename + " added ");
        //img = new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(filename))));
        img = new Image(new Texture(filename));
        img.setSize(50, 50);
        tableImages.add(img); //this does NOT WORK !
        //tableButtons.add(new TextButton("click me", skin));  //this works
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            table.add(tableImages.get(3*i + j)).size(img.getWidth(),      img.getHeight());
            //table.add(tableButtons.get(3*i + j));
        }
        table.row();
    }
    stage.addActor(table);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

}

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I've added the code. why downvote ?

Comment: Thanks. Question titles should not contain "solved", instead answers should be posted and accepted.

Comment: My bad, i just wanted to update  my findings. In any case, will keep this in mind.